# Removal of frequencies in speech below 100 Hz

Tags: filtering, signal-processing, fft, octave, speech

I tried removing all the frequencies below 100 Hz from my voice sample (with Octave) using FFT only (as I am not supposed to use any filters). However, when I play the sample, it sounds as if the waveform is distorted. After trial and error, I removed the frequencies from 2Hz to 100Hz and it was sounding better than before. My question is: since the human hearing range is from 20 Hz to 20 kHz then how can a voice sample sound better if the range is from 2 to 100 Hz ? Here is the code:

```
n1=1+round(0/fsamplingn):1+round(98/fsamplingn); --to remove the original frequencies
n2=1+n-round(98/fsn):1+n-round(0/fsn); -- to remove mirror
yf=fft(y); --fourier of voice
yf(n1)=0; yf(n2)=0;
```

Comment: You need to use overlap-add or overlap-save for frequency domain processing such as this.

Comment: Please show the code.

Comment: Kindly note that fsampling is sampling frequency which is 20khz and n is total number of samples. I am trying to make fourier transform at n1 and n2 as zero and the range is 0Hz to 98Hz. Below is the snippet: 
n1=1+round(0/fsampling*n):1+round(98/fsampling*n);  --to remove the original frequencies
n2=1+n-round(98/fs*n):1+n-round(0/fs*n);  -- to remove mirror
yf=fft(y); --fourier of voice
yf(n1)=0;
yf(n2)=0;

Comment: Please [edit] any relevant code into your question. Also please indicate whether you are aware of the need to use overlap-add/overlap-save for this type of processing, as any answers will depend on how far you have progressed with this.

Comment: I don't know anything about overlap add/save. Could you please let me know about the same. Thanks a lot!

Comment: OK - see answer below and check out the links.

Answer (score 1):

For frequency domain processing such as this you need to use either the [Overlap-add](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overlap%E2%80%93add_method) or [Overlap-save](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overlap%E2%80%93save_method) method.

Essentially you take short *overlapping* blocks of samples (typically 10 ms or 20ms or thereabouts - short enough that the block can be considered to be statistically stationary), FFT, process in frequency domain, IFFT, then add or save half of the block according to whichever of the two aforementioned methods you want to use.

Also note that you should not just arbitrarily zero out bins in the frequency domain, as this will result in artefacts ("ringing") in the time domain - you need to instead use a smooth "window" function when you transition between passband and stopband.

As for the last part of your question, speech is perfectly *intelligible* even if you filter out everything outside the range 300 Hz - 3 kHz. This is typically the frequency response used in telephony. So removing everything below 100 Hz should make very little difference. Of course the quality is better if you use the full range of say 20 Hz - 20 kHz, but we don't need all that bandwidth just for speech communication.

Comment: I understand that but I have to accomplish this task currently without any filters and using only basic fft/ifft commands. Can you let me know how can i remove mirror frequencies using the code I'd mentioned in my question. Thank you for your patience!

Comment: What you are apparently trying to achieve is high-pass filtering, and evidently your assignment is to do this with an FFT, rather then explicit filters in the time domain. This is called "frequency domain filtering". It's similar to "fast convolution". If you read the answer above and follow the links you will see how do to this in MATLAB/Octave/whatever - it just requires a few additional steps in addition to the FFT/IFFT. No actual filters required!

Comment: Sure - I've updated the answer above too with more information.

Comment: Nice answer; by the way, what OP got wrong is that he says he has an audio sampling rate of 20kHz and a 20kHz bandwidth -- since audio typically is sampled as real signal, Nyquist wouldn't allow that! The full bandwidth is 10kHz. I didn't bother to mention that in my answer either, since the absolute frequencies don't matter much, here.

Comment: Thanks - I hadn't noticed any mention of sample rate - I see you've also provided a nice detailed answer - up-votes to you too !

Answer (score 1):

> using FFT only (as I am not supposed to use any filters).

You just built a filter! To explain: Mathematically, application of a FIR to a digital signal (which I presume is what you're *not* allowed to do) is convolution of the signal with the filter tap vector.

Convolution in time domain is multiplication in frequency domain; [Paul R's remarks about overlap applying](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33159137/4433386).

What you're doing when 0-setting the frequency bins you want to suppress is multiplying in frequency domain with a

```
[0, 0, ..., 0, 1, 1, ..., 1, 0, 0, ..., 0]
```

vector.

So, you've filtered your signal, mathematically 100% equivalent to applying a FIR-filter that you reset every FFT length samples.

To illustrate: We'll use the frequency domain mask

```
[1]*400+[0]*224+[1]*400
```

with a 1024-FFT. GNU Radio has an implementation of a properly overlapping FFT filter, so we can directly compare the effect of that with the effect of a FIR filter; because both GNU Radio filter implementations take time domain taps, we'll have to IDFT the frequency domain taps first¹. We then stimulate the filters with Gaussian Noise coming from a highly white source. The overall system looks like:

[image: GNU Radio companion Flow Graph]

and when run, produces the following plot:

[image: Frequency domain analysis]

Notice how the FIR and the FFT filter response lay atop of each other *perfectly*; that's no surprise, as they are *mathematically equivalent*.

---

¹  to do this completely properly, I'd have to apply a window to these taps first, as this is what the FFT filter of GNU Radio does, too, but that'd leave the scope of your question so significantly that I decided not to do it; hence, the filter response isn't very sharp or deep, but has strong overshoot at the passband edges.

Comment: Thanks for all that information. However, I am neither supposed to use overlap method or anything related to filters. I am just supposed to use fft and remove bins, even though its not the best method. Would really appreciate if helped in the same direction. Thanks

Comment: **you're building a filter** with what you do. No use telling yourself you're not allowed to build a filter.